# How to transfer variadic parameter in Swift

Tags: swift, parameters, variadic

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    var result = 0
    for number in numbers {
        result += number
    }
    return result
}

let a1 = sumOf(numbers: 1, 2, 4, 10)

func sampleOfSum(nums: Int...) -> Int {
    return sumOf(numbers: nums)// Error: Cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to expected argument type 'Int'
}
```

Comment: yes, same question, thanks.

Comment: i personally would prefer the [Int] function parameters. in the most cases you calculare over an array

Comment: btw: a sum over an array you write faster like this: `let sum = [4,5,9].reduce(0,{$0+$1})`

Comment: @muescha good suggestion.